# Using Bootstrap 3 popover and loading external JSON

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am loading external JSON and would like to use Bootstrap popvers.

Their sample code is like:

HTML:

```
<button data-toggle="popover" title="Dismissible popover" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">jonathan</button>
```

and presumably:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
```

However, it would seem since this is from loaded JSON, I would have to do something like:

```
$('body').on('click', '[data-toggle="popover"]', function(){
  // would I call somehtig like 
  $(this).popover();
});
```

The only way I can get this to work is like:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('body').on('click','[data-toggle="popover"]', function(){
    //alert('here i am');
    $(this).popover();

  });
});
```

and it only works on the second click. How would I implement this? I'd rather have it just be a hover rather than a click too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the popover to come on the second click is the way you're initializing your popover.

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('body').on('click','[data-toggle="popover"]', function(){
    //alert('here i am');
    $(this).popover();

  });
});
```

Here you're initializing without any options so the default trigger for your popover will be `click` event and you're doing this initialization when you click on the `body`. That's the reason you need 2 clicks to show the popover.

To avoid this, you need to register the `popover` on your button on `page load` and define the trigger of your interest (click or hover) using `data-trigger` attribute in HTML.

**HTML**

```
  <a id="example" tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" 
       role="button" data-toggle="popover" 
       data-trigger="hover" title="Dismissible popover" 
       data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very 
       engaging. Right?">
     Dismissible popover
  </a>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#example').popover();
});
```

You can also define the trigger and other [options](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-options) while initializing the popover like below.

```
$('#example2').popover({
    trigger : 'hover'
  });
```

Here's a [Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWmRqO) to showcase the implementation.

Comment: so I agree with your pen and what you are saying. I think it's because the DOM isn't fully loaded due to the async call, the popover method isn't working correclty. Or would popver account for that already?

Comment: If you're loading your button (for this button you need a popover) in an async call, then you need to initialize the popver on that button once you add it to DOM probably in the success callback of your async call

Comment: ah thx, sorry it's about midnight here so a bit slow :/ thx for the help